# Generating vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I am wondering whether there is an efficient way in MATLAB to generate all vectors of a fixed length with elements from a finite set.

For instance, how can I build all vectors of length 5 with only 0 or 1 as elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not quite what you need, but permv generates vector permutations. If you do not find exact solution, you can adapt vector permutations.

[permv](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/perms.html)

Comment: @Kiran: Keep in mind that you have to first choose a 5-element vector of ones and zeroes to start with, then PERMS will give you every permutation of that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, gnovice. This makes my code much quicker then earlier and that is really good.

Answer (score 10):

The proper way to build all vectors of length 5 with only 0 or 1 as elements is

```
a = dec2bin(0:31,5) - '0';
```

I hope you see why.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. The only possible drawback is that DEC2BIN can be *painfully* slow.

Comment: @gnovice: You've made me go and look at DEC2BIN source. Yes, it's probably not very efficient - but it's such a cute one-liner! Thanks.

Comment: Rather than looping, get used to not looping.

>> tic,a=zeros(10,1024);for x=0:1023,a(:,x+1)=str2num(dec2bin(x,10)');end,toc

Elapsed time is 0.105492 seconds.

>> tic,a = dec2bin(0:1023) - '0';toc
Elapsed time is 0.000868 seconds.

Comment: @woodchips: Well, the `-'0'` is a cool trick I didn't know about, so I couldn't vectorize that loop (I tried, of course). Thanks! I'll edit my answer - this makes it a one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

MathWorks' [FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) is your friend:

- [VChooseKRO](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26242)
- [COMBN](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-combn)
- [COMBINATOR](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations)
- [NPERMUTEK](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11462-npermutek)

So using the first function, its as easy as:

```
VChooseKRO([0 1], 5)
```

You can even make it work for a cell array of strings as the finite set:

```
C = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'};
C( VChooseKRO(1:numel(C), 2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

**New answer:**

You can speed up the [DEC2BIN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dec2bin.html) solution [suggested by AB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344049/generating-vectors-in-matlab/2344425#2344425) (with an assist by [woodchips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85109/woodchips)) by instead using the [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) function. There are two ways to approach this. The first uses the [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) function to make the inputs equal in size (both 32-by-5 matrices):

```
allCombos = bitget(repmat((0:31)',1,5),repmat(5:-1:1,32,1));
```

And the second simply calls [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) once for every individual bit you want to get:

```
vec = (0:31)';
allCombos = [bitget(vec,5) bitget(vec,4) bitget(vec,3) ...
             bitget(vec,2) bitget(vec,1)];
```

And here are some sample timings:

```
     Method      |  Average Time
-----------------+------------------
  DEC2BIN        |   0.000788 s
  BITGET+REPMAT  |   0.000727 s
  BITGET x5      |   0.000045 s
```

As you can see, the unrolled [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) is very fast.

---

**Old answer: (for posterity)**

If you are wanting to build a matrix of *every possible vector* of zeroes and ones that has a length of 5, this would be one way to do it using the functions [PERMS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/perms.html) and [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) (since [PERMS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/perms.html) creates repeated rows):

```
allCombos = [0 0 0 0 0;
             unique(perms([0 0 0 0 1]),'rows'); ...
             unique(perms([0 0 0 1 1]),'rows'); ...
             unique(perms([0 0 1 1 1]),'rows'); ...
             unique(perms([0 1 1 1 1]),'rows'); ...
             1 1 1 1 1];
```